# How can I make a span cover the full width of a div in this specific example?

Tags: html, css

I've been struggling with this problem after searching stack overflow/google for a couple hours...

I can't seem to get this span to cover the full width of its parent div without using display: inline-block, but when I use that, it seems like it acts just like a div and is no longer in-line? It cuts off the dividing bar, as seen in the image I linked.

How can I make this span stay inline, cover the full width of the div, and not cut off the dividing bar?

[image: Image of the issue]

I apologize for what probably is very sloppy HTML/CSS

```css
.chatroom {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;

  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity:.8;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.form-control{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

#chat{
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  float: right;
  height:100%;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#channels{
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  width:25%;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#bar{
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;
  float: right;
  width: 3px;
}
#contain{
  height:100%;
}
.channel{
  text-indent: 30%;
  font-size:20px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: rgba(193, 66, 66, 0.23);
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatroom">
  <div id="contain">
    <div id="channels">
      <span class="channel">General</span>
        <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
      <ul id="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <div class="input">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="m" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `float: left` on your span (and remove the `display:inline-block`). Also, set the width of the span to `width:calc(100% - 3px)` *(we remove the 3px of the bar)*.

However, I do not know what you want to do but maybe it's better to use a table?

```css
.chatroom {
  width: 90vw;
  height: 80vh;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: fixed;

  border: 2px solid white;
  border-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  opacity:.8;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;

}
.input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 98%;
  margin-left:1%;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.form-control{
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 30px;
}

#chat{
  border-top-right-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
  float: right;
  height:100%;
  width: 75%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
#channels{
  border-top-left-radius: 30px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  width:25%;
  float: left;
  height:100%;
  overflow-y: hidden;
}
#bar{
  background-color:black;
  height:100%;
  float: right;
  width: 3px;
}
#contain{
  height:100%;
}
.channel{
  text-indent: 30%;
  font-size:20px;
  width:calc(100% - 3px);
  background-color: rgba(193, 66, 66, 0.23);
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="chatroom">
  <div id="contain">
    <div id="channels">
      <span class="channel">General</span>
        <div id="bar"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="chat">
      <ul id="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li>{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
      <div class="input">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" id="m" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```